# Problem in writing regular expression for imenu-generic-expression

Tags: regular-expressions, imenu

I want to use imenu in `matlab-mode` in emacs. So I add something like

```
(setq imenu-generic-expression
      '(("Function"
         "\\(function\\)[\n\t ]*\\[?[ ,_A-Za-z0-9]+\\]?[\n\t ]*=[\n\t ]*\\([_A-Za-z0-9]+\\)" 2)
        ("Anonymous Function"
         "\\([_A-Za-z0-9]+\\)[\n\t ]*=[\n\t ]*@[\n\t ]*([, _A-Za-z0-9]+)" 1)))
```

in a function for `matlab-mode-hook`.

The matlab function definitions are something like

```
function y = func1 (x)
end

function [y, z] = func2 (a, b, c)
end

func3 = @(x) sin(x) + cos(x);
```

The above config results in something like

```
Function / func1
Function / func2
Anonymous Funtion / 3
```

after the `helm-semantic-or-imenu` or `ido-imenu` commands are launched.

My question is why the regular expression for anonymous function did not capture the function name `fun3` as expected but `3`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to anchor the name with a `\_<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happens, but imenu seems to match the regexp in a non-greedy manner, so it matched `3` rather than `func3`.

If you change the regexp to the following, it will match `func3`. The difference is the `\\_<` in front of the regexp matching the variable name:

```
(setq imenu-generic-expression
  '(("Function"
     "\\(function\\)[\n\t ]*\\[?[ ,_A-Za-z0-9]+\\]?[\n\t ]*=[\n\t ]*\\([_A-Za-z0-9]+\\)" 2)
    ("Anonymous Function"
     "\\_<\\([_A-Za-z0-9]+\\)[\n\t ]*=[\n\t ]*@[\n\t ]*([, _A-Za-z0-9]+)" 1)))
```

Comment: Imenu searches bottom up.